# How to install nvm with curl script?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, curl, nvm

I am trying to install nvm using curl on ubuntu 20.04. I am getting below error messages when nvm is installed through curl. Is there any other flag that needs to be attached to supress below error?

Machine configuration:

- vm: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
- curl: curl 7.68.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Commands:

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt install curl

#installing nvm

curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | bash

source ~/.bashrc
```

Error Message:
curl: (92) HTTP/2 stream 0 was closed cleanly, but before getting  all response header fields, treated as error

Comment: Did you try `wget` instead of `curl` ?  `wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | bash`

Comment: I think your network is down. It works for me.

Comment: I just successfully installed it in my Linux Mint, which i think is based on Ubuntu, running curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.3/install.sh | bash as explained here: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#install--update-script